# How can I update my Gradle version in Unity to fix build errors?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Problem appeared when I used downloaded assets of prefabs.

Build fails of gradle error. I tried to change gradle version or update it but unity uses 6.1.1 version.

I can provide path to new gradle version but unity uses only old version.

Old version is somehow connected to project and unity don't change version.

[image]

There is a photo of error that may can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.